# CSS, automatically change styles like size, etc. if font is not found and alternative is used

Tags: css, fonts

If the font I am using couldn't be loaded or is not found, the alternate font will be used. If so, I need to change some other styles like `font-weight`, `letter-spacing`, `font-size`, etc.

for example:

```
div {
      font-family:"Lemon",sans-serif;
    }
```

Here Lemon is a really thick font, so the way I style this font might not be suitable for the alternative font. So if the first specified font could not be loaded, how can I change style of the alternative font accordingly?

Comment: The only method I have found so far is rather old, and also likely to be time consuming, [link] https://github.com/philoye/fontunstack/tree/master

Comment: @AHaworth Thanks but, It would be better if it could be done using css or vanilla js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caveat: this method should be able to detect whether any non monospaced font is loaded or not.

It appears it is not possible to sense the actual font in use using CSS alone. Taking ideas from font.js highlighted in @Eddie Reeder answer and also from [github.com/philoye/fontunstack/tree/master](http://github.com/philoye/fontunstack/tree/master) we can measure the required font against another font. I have chosen a monospace font to test against and a string of narrow characters (i) as being the most likely to be different from the required font.
Code like this (which I've deliberately spelled out to make clear what is going on) placed possibly in the head or at the start of body. It could of course be placed in a function to be called at the start and/or made to remove its test divs once the required script has been set up and/or to set CSS variables if that makes more sense than having two separate css style files.

```
<div id="maybeOurFont" style="font-family: Lemon, monospace; font-size: 100px; position: absolute; left: -9999px; top:0;">iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</div>
<div id="testFont" style="font-family: monospace; font-size: 100px; position: absolute; left: -9999px; top:0;">iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</div>
<script>
  const pathToLemonStyle = "lemonstyle.css"; //replace with your path
  const pathToNoLemonstyle = "nolemonstyle.css"; // ditto
  const lemonLength = document.getElementById("maybeOurFont").offsetWidth;
  const monoLength = document.getElementById("testFont").offsetWidth;
  let useThisStyle = pathToLemonStyle;
  if ( lemonLength == monoLength ) {
    useThisStyle= pathToNoLemonstyle;
  }
  document.head.append('<style src="' + useThisStyle + '"></style>');
</script>
```

Comment: Good to know that we don't need jQuery or other plugins, but there will be fonts with same width. Thanks any way.

Comment: Will there be fonts with fixed width, monospaced. Most fonts aren’t so this method should work to detect any non monospaced font. I’d assumed Lemon wasn’t monospaced. I’ll add that caveat to the answer.

Comment: @A Haworth Yes lemon isn't monospaced but, the idea is not to use a monospace font as an alternative font and check whether the first font is used or not. The idea is that if the first font is not used then style the second font accordingly, which may or may not be a monospaced font.

Comment: That’s fine. The monospaced font is used only to check if lemon is there, once checked we either load a css file that deals with lemon being available or if not we load the css file that deals with it not being available. Of course if you have only very slight differences in a few places you may want to load a common css file and just add the bits of css that are different for the non lemon situation.

Answer (score 1):

Using pure CSS, you *can't*. One option would be to use javascript to [detect if a font is installed](https://remysharp.com/2008/07/08/how-to-detect-if-a-font-is-installed-only-using-javascript/), then adjust your styles accordingly.

Something like:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  font.setup(); // run setup when the DOM is ready

  if (!font.isInstalled("Lemon")) {
    document.getElementById("example-div").style.fontWeight = "900";
  }
});
```

This utilises [font.js](https://remysharp.com/downloads/font.js) which must be included in your page.

Comment: To be honest, the [font.js](https://remysharp.com/downloads/font.js) script is so small. You could just copy the code into your own JS file, sort of making it vanilla JS... :)

Comment: Yes, it does look as though the only way to do this, used both here and in the old github fontunstack, is basically to look at the width of a string of mmmms plus other chars and see if it’s the same as the Lemon or other desired font. Seems a bit hacky and hit and miss, but probably would work in this case of a ‘fat’ font versus slimmer ones. Shame it can’t be done in CSS. Maybe use a fixed font for comparison?